# Code to fill in zeros for dataframe with multiple descriptors

Tags: r

I have large data files that contain three columns: Description, Index, Value.
Description is text that is a category for the data.
Index is a 1:n index and Value is a numeric value.

My issue is that the raw data contains majority rows where Value=0.0
I can reduce the size of the files by applying a filter(Value!=0) to the dataframe and then restore the result. However, when performing analysis of the data, I need the zeros returned to the dataframe.

So, I start with the following example data

| Description | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 1 | 2.0 |
| D1 | 2 | 0.0 |
| D1 | 3 | 1.0 |
| D2 | 1 | 0.0 |
| D2 | 2 | 0.0 |
| D2 | 3 | 3.0 |
| D3 | 1 | 0.0 |
| D3 | 2 | 5.0 |
| D3 | 3 | 4.0 |

In the raw data, all descriptors will have values for the same 1:n index

After removing all zero values the data becomes

| Description | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 1 | 2.0 |
| D1 | 3 | 1.0 |
| D2 | 3 | 3.0 |
| D3 | 2 | 5.0 |
| D3 | 3 | 4.0 |

My question is how do I get from the second table back to the first table?
Assume that every factor in the Description will have at least one non-zero value.

My solution is as follows using the following functions with appropriate values

1. use rbind() to add a dummy set of values that look like the following:
   since index is 1:3

| Description | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dummy | 1 | (any number) |
| Dummy | 2 | (any number) |
| Dummy | 3 | (any number) |

2. use pivot_wider() filling all missing values with 0.0 to create a wide version of the desired dataframe
3. use pivot_longer() to transpose the data back into tidyverse form
4. use filter(Description!="Dummy") to take out the Dummy rows.

This works, but is there a better way?
I don't want to have to create large "dummy" index files where n is super large.
Also, with large index values, manually defining the two pivot_() functions is a hassle.
Help please :-)

Comment: use `complete(index)` or `full_join(df)`

Comment: Why do you want to filter(Value != 0) in the first place, when you need the complete data set for your analysis? What do you need the reduced sample for?

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag and in particular provide the inputs in reproducible form using `dput`.  I have done it for you this time in the Note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: zeros are removed to facilitate storage. actual files are multi GB size and I have limited storage capability.

Answer (score 1):

**1) complete** Assuming the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `complete` as shown.  Here `tib` is the full tibble and `tib_sub` is the one without the zeros.

```
library(tidyr)

tib2 <- complete(tib_sub, Description, Index, fill = list(Value = 0))
identical(tib, tib2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) Base R** A solution returning a data.frame using only base R is:

```
g <- with(tib_sub, expand.grid(Index = unique(Index), 
  Description = unique(Description))[2:1]
transform(merge(tib_sub, g, all = TRUE), Value = replace(Value, is.na(Value), 0))
```

### Note

```
tib <- structure(list(Description = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D3", "D3", "D3"), Index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), Value = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 4)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

tib_sub <- dplyr::filter(tib, Value > 0)
```